# splash screen issue in blackberry z 10 using phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10

I am developing an application in Blackberry through Phonegap. while i'm developing the application, i'm not getting the `Splash Screen`.I tried all the procedures provided by phonegap official site, but i didn't get so please provide the solution ASAP

Comment: Show your Code, What u have tried..

Comment: BTW which webworks version?